# apache drill jdbc 1.1.0 build issue

Tags: maven, apache-drill

I am building apache drill 1.1.0 from its [source](https://github.com/apache/drill). I got the following error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Drill Root POM ............................. SUCCESS [8.234s]
[INFO] Drill Protocol .................................... SUCCESS [6.639s]
[INFO] Common (Logical Plan, Base expressions) ........... SUCCESS [50.152s]
[INFO] contrib/Parent Pom ................................ SUCCESS [0.717s]
[INFO] contrib/data/Parent Pom ........................... SUCCESS [0.365s]
[INFO] contrib/data/tpch-sample-data ..................... SUCCESS [4.968s]
[INFO] exec/Parent Pom ................................... SUCCESS [0.545s]
[INFO] exec/Java Execution Engine ........................ FAILURE [38.896s]
[INFO] exec/JDBC Driver using dependencies ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] JDBC JAR with all dependencies .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/mongo-storage-plugin ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hbase-storage-plugin ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/Parent Pom ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/hive-exec-shaded ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/hive-storage-plugin/core .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Packaging and Distribution Assembly ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] contrib/sqlline ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:51.105s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 10 07:24:19 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/325M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project drill-java-exec: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.apache.drill.exec:drill-java-exec:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   transfer artifact net.hydromatic:foodmart-data-json:jar:0.4 from/to
>   central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of:
>   net/hydromatic/foodmart-data-json/0.4/foodmart-data-json-0.4.jar from
>   central failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body
>   (expected: 18196233; received: 17400 -> [Help 1]

**Edit:**

I checked the jar in `.m2/repository`. It contains `foodmart-data-json-0.4.jar.lastUpdated`, `foodmart-data-json-0.4.pom.lastUpdated`, `foodmart-data-json-0.4.pom`, `foodmart-data-json-0.4.pom.sha1`, `_maven.repositories`. When I opened `foodmart-data-json-0.4.jar.lastUpdated` in text editor. I found:

```
#NOTE: This is an internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Aug 10 08:44:18 IST 2015
http\://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/repositories/drill/.lastUpdated=1439176430716
default-http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1439176458509
http\://conjars.org/repo/.lastUpdated=1439176430238
http\://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/repositories/drill/.error=
http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact net.hydromatic\:foodmart-data-json\:jar\:0.4 from/to central (http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: GET request of\: net/hydromatic/foodmart-data-json/0.4/foodmart-data-json-0.4.jar from central failed
http\://conjars.org/repo/.error=
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Seems like a network issue with downloading jar. Open the file that got downloaded - maybe its a message from your firewall instead of a jar

Comment: @6ton how to resolve this?

Comment: What do you see in the jar file that got downloaded - open it in text editor.

Comment: @6ton please find my updated question.

Comment: Try downloading the jar in your browser - looks like a network/firewall issue to me

Comment: @6ton I downloaded the jar manually. It works... Thanks